# Effect of short term high VM memory usage (Windows)

Tags: windows, caching, virtual-memory

In the app I'm writing, I use a lot of in memory containers (C++ std containers but I don't think that's relevant).

During one "task" of my app, in a heavy usage edge-case the private bytes memory usage hits 1GB.

Just as a bit of context, this task is a user initiated task involving 100,000s files. It's likely that the user will kick this off and then leave the machine running.

(And no I don't do anything dumb like load files into memory - this footprint is all metadata related to the task in progress).

For most users the memory usage during this task is negligable - it's just the 1% of users who want to do 500,000 "things" insted of 5000 "things".

I was about to embark on a process to move a lot of this in-memory stuff to disk somehow, e.g. scratch file, embedded DB.

But then I thought - "hang on a minute. All of these solutions are essentially caching memory to disk. Isn't that what Virtual Memory is for?".

I'm not interested in persisting this data - it's purely scratch/temporary stuff I need access to while the task is running.

So my question is, what should I do?

I don't want to do a major refactor for that 1%, but I want to know the impact of running an app with that high a memory footprint.

Am I right in saying that I probably wouldn't be able to do much better than the Windows VM manager anyway?

Under what conditions does this become harmful? OK so yes, if I used up all the real memory then it'd be thrashing to reload pages. But wouldn't I have that anyway in the case if e.g. an embedded database?

Cheers,

John

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the memory manager will do the job for you.  Not without side-effects though, it is going to evict pages from RAM that other processes have mapped and give them to you.  Those other processes are going to get slowed down by this, they'll be hit with a page fault when they access such a swapped-out page.

The balancing act here is whether your app is "important" enough to justify those other processes from getting short shrift.  Usually that's Yes on a work station, a resounding No on a server.